# How to Connect two Tables with @OneToOne connection in Java Annotation using MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I created two tables "instructor" and "instructor_detail" in MySQL. Then I Joined them using @OneToOne Annotation.

**I am getting the Below Error-:**

```
Aug 24, 2022 5:53:06 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.11.Final}
Aug 24, 2022 5:53:07 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Aug 24, 2022 5:53:07 PM com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector <clinit>
SEVERE: null
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:573)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.<clinit>(Injector.java:197)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:81)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:179)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:285)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:94)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:514)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:331)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1156)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:165)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:297)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:286)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:409)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at com.mandeep.hibernate.demo.CreateDemo.main(CreateDemo.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2227)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$3.run(Injector.java:201)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$3.run(Injector.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    ... 32 more

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object[])" because "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.defineClass" is null
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:97)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:87)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:179)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:285)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:94)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:514)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:331)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1156)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:165)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:297)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:286)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:409)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at com.mandeep.hibernate.demo.CreateDemo.main(CreateDemo.java:15)
```

**The Main Class "CreateDemo" is As below-:** *The Error is in SessionFactory(hibernate.cfg.xml)||I dont know how to solve it though*

```
package com.mandeep.hibernate.demo;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.mandeep.hibernate.demo.entity.Instructor;
import com.mandeep.hibernate.demo.entity.InstructorDetail;

public class CreateDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                .addAnnotatedClass(Instructor.class)
                                .addAnnotatedClass(InstructorDetail.class)
                                .buildSessionFactory();
        
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        
        try {
            
            //create objects
            Instructor tempInstructor = 
                    new Instructor("Meenakshi","Sharma","ABC@gmail.com");
            
            InstructorDetail tempInstructorDetail = 
                    new InstructorDetail("www.youtube.com","Art");
            
            //associate the objects
            tempInstructor.setInstructorDetail(tempInstructorDetail);
            
            //start Transaction
            session.beginTransaction();
            
            //save the Instructor
            System.out.println("Saving Instructor " + tempInstructor);
            session.save(tempInstructor);
            
            //commit transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            
            
            
        }
        finally {
            factory.close();
            
        }
    }

}
```

**The "hibernate.cfg.xml" file is as below-:**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb-01-one-to-one-uni?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">hbstudent</property>
        <property name="connection.password">hbstudent</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
 
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**The "Instructor Class is as below-:"**

```
package com.mandeep.hibernate.demo.entity;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="instructor")
public class Instructor {
    
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="instructor_detail_id")
    private InstructorDetail instructorDetail;  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    
    public Instructor() {
        
    }

    public Instructor(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public InstructorDetail getInstructorDetail() {
        return instructorDetail;
    }

    public void setInstructorDetail(InstructorDetail instructorDetail) {
        this.instructorDetail = instructorDetail;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Instructor [instructorDetail=" + instructorDetail + ", id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName
                + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

**The "InsructorDetail" Class is as below-:**

```
package com.mandeep.hibernate.demo.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="instructor_detail")
public class InstructorDetail {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="youtube_channel")
    private String youtubeChannel;
    
    @Column(name="hobby")
    private String hobby;

    public InstructorDetail() {
        
    }

    public InstructorDetail(String youtubeChannel, String hobby) {
        this.youtubeChannel = youtubeChannel;
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getYoutubeChannel() {
        return youtubeChannel;
    }

    public void setYoutubeChannel(String youtubeChannel) {
        this.youtubeChannel = youtubeChannel;
    }

    public String getHobby() {
        return hobby;
    }

    public void setHobby(String hobby) {
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "InstructorDetail [id=" + id + ", youtubeChannel=" + youtubeChannel + ", hobby=" + hobby + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: I just Got the Link.Sorry For Toruble. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71138619/error-while-creating-building-a-hibernate-app

Answer (score 0):

based on that error

> java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionDomain)

I would suggest checking if there is a missing dependency in the `build.gradle` / `pom.xml` (whether you use Gradle or Maven).

Comment: i dont have any pom.xmlor build.gradle.It is pure java project not javaEE

Comment: Oh you will need to add `Gradle` or `Maven` mate, its a lot easier to add dependencies (which you need) from `mvnrepository.com` instead of downloading them one by one and putting them in `External Libraries` as projects. I'd strongly suggest doing that. There's plenty of tutorials on YT describing how to do that, you can even do it via `springinitializr.com`

Comment: Please provide a full answer or post it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

The error is that your JAXB implementation uses a method from the JDK that was removed, so the Java version with which you are trying to run your application is not supported by the jaxb implementation you are depending on. Try updating, e.g. use:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```